# TCPTransportSender cannot be found by axis2_1.6.1.wso2v15 in WSO2 DSS 3.5.0

Tags: wso2, apache-axis, wso2-data-services-server

I am upgrading WSO2 DSS 3.2.2 server to 3.5.0, but I am eventually getting this error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.axis2.transport.tcp.TCPTransportSender cannot be found by axis2_1.6.1.wso2v15
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:501)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:421)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:412)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.DefaultClassLoader.loadClass(DefaultClassLoader.java:107)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:195)
    at org.apache.axis2.util.Loader.loadClass(Loader.java:261)
    at org.apache.axis2.deployment.AxisConfigBuilder.processTransportSenders(AxisConfigBuilder.java:686)
```

Is this a configuration problem or do I need to add a particular JAR library? If yes, which one?

**Edit**: I have just found that axis2_1.6.1.wso2v10.jar has this org.apache.axis2.transport.tcp.TCPTransportSender class but axis2_1.6.1.wso2v15.jar doesn't.

Comment: when are you getting this error? Also can you tell how did you upgrade from DSS 3.2.2 to 3.5.0

Comment: What I mean by upgrade is just migration (I copied my data-services to a new installation). This error appears when I am starting WSO2 server.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This error was solved by adding **axis2-transport-tcp-1.0.0.jar** to ..repository/components/dropins.