# wso2am Managing Users and Roles with APIs example class not found

Tags: java, intellij-idea, wso2, wso2-api-manager, wso2-identity-server

I want to programm a spring boot app, that can managing users in wso2am. Therefore I tried to run the example from the wso2 identity server docs. (https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS500/Managing+Users+and+Roles+with+APIs)

I've download the example, open it in IntelliJ and add the hole plugins-folder as dependencies in the projektstructure. But when I compile the example, I get a ClassNotFoundException.

```
org.apache.axis2.deployment.DeploymentException: org.apache.axis2.transport.tcp.TCPTransportSender
    at org.apache.axis2.deployment.AxisConfigBuilder.processTransportSenders(AxisConfigBuilder.java:712)
    at org.apache.axis2.deployment.AxisConfigBuilder.populateConfig(AxisConfigBuilder.java:124)
    at org.apache.axis2.deployment.DeploymentEngine.populateAxisConfiguration(DeploymentEngine.java:887)
    at org.apache.axis2.deployment.FileSystemConfigurator.getAxisConfiguration(FileSystemConfigurator.java:116)
    at org.apache.axis2.context.ConfigurationContextFactory.createConfigurationContext(ConfigurationContextFactory.java:64)
    at org.apache.axis2.context.ConfigurationContextFactory.createConfigurationContextFromFileSystem(ConfigurationContextFactory.java:210)
    at org.wso2.identity.um.sample.IdentityServerClient.main(IdentityServerClient.java:61)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:147)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.axis2.transport.tcp.TCPTransportSender
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:264)
    at org.apache.axis2.util.Loader.loadClass(Loader.java:261)
    at org.apache.axis2.deployment.AxisConfigBuilder.processTransportSenders(AxisConfigBuilder.java:686)
    ... 11 more
```

What do I wrong, that even the example didn't run?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a version compatibility issue. IS 5.0.0 has `axis2_1.6.1.wso2v10.jar`. But APIM 2.0.0 (I assume that's what you're using) has `axis2_1.6.1.wso2v19.jar`. The new version does not have `org.apache.axis2.transport.tcp.TCPTransportSender` class for some reason. [See this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34306057/tcptransportsender-cannot-be-found-by-axis2-1-6-1-wso2v15-in-wso2-dss-3-5-0).

So if you use `axis2_1.6.1.wso2v10.jar`, it should work.